# Save last login date in global before change it?

Tags: login, globals

I use this function to get the last time a user logged in.

```
function jkn_last_login($user_login) {
    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $user_login );
    global $last_login;
    $last_login = array();
    $last_login[$user->ID] = get_user_meta($user->ID,'last-login',true);
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last-login', time() );
}
add_action('wp_login','jkn_last_login',12,3);
```

As you can see i define a global `$last_login` to save the last login time.

But if i try to echo the value of `$last_login` nothing happen.

```
global $last_login;
global $current_user;
echo $last_login[$current_user->ID];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables. You can do it like this without global variable:

```
global $current_user;
echo get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'last-login', true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use the global keyword twice?

Try...

`global $current_user, $last_login;
 echo $last_login[$current_user->ID];`